# Casting to Custom Class Type

Tags: c#, .net

I am attempting to convert a string value passed along with the "Tag" property of a button to custom type "DialogClosingEventArgs" as shown:

```
var converted = (DialogClosingEventArgs)((Button)sender).Tag;
```

However during runtime I get the following exception: "*Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.DialogClosingEventArgs'*"

How can I force this conversion?

Comment: It's not possible to cast a `string` to `DialogClosingEventArgs` and there is no way of doing that as those are two completely different types

Comment: Why are you attempting that particular cast? Did you expect the object in the tag to *be* an object of that type? Was the string unexpected? Please elaborate on why you think "forcing" this cast would even be possible.

Answer (score 0):

To cast an object to a type, it must be compatible with the type you cast. As you say, it is a `string` so simply it is not Castable to `DialogClosingEventArgs`.

Works:

```
button.Tag = 3;
int a = (int)button.Tag;
```

Doesn't Work:

```
button.Tag = "some string";
int a = (int)button.Tag;
```

Because string cannot be cast to int.